# How to get the ID from table database into link using vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

I have a system where when user click button submit it will insert the data into the table database and also send an email to the user. My problem is I want to put a link into the email.Body so that the user can click the link to the Approval page. But when I click the link it says `the sites can't be reached` and the `id=0`. Every Functions work well, I just have a problem with the link.

Here is my sendMessage() code :

```
  Private Sub SendMessage()
        Dim mail As MailMessage = New MailMessage

        mail.From = New MailAddress("notice@example.com")
        mail.To.Add(New MailAddress("user1@example.com"))

        mail.Subject = "Test Approval"

        Dim link As String
        Dim intID As Integer

        link = "<a href=""http://localhost:" & "/test/test.aspx?id=" & LoadEmployeeDetailsById(intID) & """>Click here</a>"
        mail.Body = "<br/><br/>Employee No : " & lblEmpNO.Text.Trim(Environment.NewLine, "<br />") & "<br/><br/>Employee Name : " & lblemployeename.Text.Trim & link


        mail.IsBodyHtml = True
        Dim client As New SmtpClient()
        client.EnableSsl = True
        Try
            client.Send(mail)
            'MsgBox("Sending Email succeeded")
        Catch ex As Exception
            'MsgBox("Sending Email failed. Please try again")
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Here is LoadEmployeeDetailsById(intID) :

```
   Private Function LoadEmployeeDetailsById(ByVal intid As Integer) As String
        Using GetdutyDetails As New clsExternalWorkDuty_func
            Dim dt As New DataTable
            Dim result As String = ""
            dt = GetdutyDetails.GetAllDataTableExternalWorkdutyDetailsByID(intid) 'Call the Function from AppCode
            If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                pnlApproval.Visible = True 
            End If
            Return result
        End Using
    End Function
```

Here is btnSubmit() :

```
 Protected Sub btnSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click
      If InsertData(lblhdddnuserid.Text, lblhddnEmployeedeptid.Text) = 1 Then
          DisplayMessage("success", "Done", "Data succesfully inserted!")
          SendMessage()
          LoadEmployeeByuserid(Membership.GetUser.ProviderUserKey)
      End If
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL must be modified to return a scalar value of the Id. If the ID is an `IDENTITY` column then you can call `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTIY()` at the end of your statement. Or you can use the `OUTPUT` directive, as below:

```
INSERT INTO [YourTable] ([Field1], [Field2], [Field3])
OUTPUT INSERTED.ID VALUES (@Value1, @Value2, @Value3)
```

The adjust your `InsertData` function to return an object as the result

```
Public Class InsertDataResult
    Public Property Success As Boolean
    Public Property InsertedId As Integer
End Class
```

Comment: Thanks ! But it still doesn't work for me.